# What is the typing of props.style in styled.TouchableOpacity component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, styled-components

Using `react-native` and `styled-components` with TypeScript,

I want to know what is the typing of `props.style` in `styled.TouchableOpacity` component in order to be able to wrap style on it, ex:

```
const Boutton = styled.TouchableOpacity

const Test = () => <Button />

const WrapTest = styled(Test)({
 // add styled
})
```

In order to do that, I must have the proper type to satisfy TypeScript:

```
const Test = (props) => <Button style={props.style} />
```

I have tried to use `style?: StyleProps<ViewStyle>`, but it gives me the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Omit<Omit<TouchableOpacityProps & RefAttributes<TouchableOpacity> & { activeOpacity: 0.7; } & ContainerProps, "activeOpacity"> & Partial<...>, "theme"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").StyleProp<import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ViewStyle>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/styled-components/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").StyleProp<import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/styled-components/node_modules/@types/react-native/index...'.
      Type 'ViewStyle' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ViewStyle>'.
        Type 'import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ViewStyle' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/styled-components/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ViewStyle'.
          Types of property 'backgroundColor' are incompatible.
            Type 'import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ColorValue | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/styled-components/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ColorValue | undefined'.
              Type 'OpaqueColorValue' is not assignable to type 'ColorValue | undefined'.
                Type 'OpaqueColorValue' is not assignable to type 'unique symbol'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof TouchableOpacity, DefaultTheme, { activeOpacity: 0.7; } & ContainerProps, "activeOpacity", typeof TouchableOpacity>): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").StyleProp<import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ViewStyle>' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/styled-components/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").StyleProp<import("/home/dka/workspace/github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/node_modules/@types/styled-components/node_modules/@types/react-native/index...'.  TS2769

    76 |       inline={inline}
    77 |       inlineHeight={inlineHeight ?? 16}
  > 78 |       style={style}>
       |       ^
    79 |       {isLoading ? (
    80 |         <Logo
    81 |           {...accessibilityAndTestId('button-isloading-icon')}
```

This is where I want to setup the props: https://github.com/pass-culture/pass-culture-app-native/blob/master/src/ui/components/buttons/AppButton.tsx#L24

What is the Typing of `props.style` for `styled.TouchableOpacity` in `react-native` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming react-native version is 0.64.2, the answer should be `StyleProp<ViewStyle> | undefined`.

`TouchableOpacity` extends `TouchableOpacityBase`, which has the type of `TouchableOpacityComponent`, which extends `React.Component<TouchableOpacityProps>`.

If you look into `TouchableOpacityProps`, you will see that it extends `TouchableWithoutFeedbackProps`, which has its `style` prop typed with :
`StyleProp<ViewStyle> | undefined`.

(Following the question description's update) Furthermore, you need to use the `TouchableOpacity` component directly imported from `react-native` : `styled(TouchableOpacity)` instead of `styled.TouchableOpacity`.

Comment: it does not work with my typescript version, I've updated my question with extra details

Comment: `styled(TouchableOpacity)` did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Type of a style prop is `ViewStyle` (like it is written in the docs `style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>`). This is generally true for basic components, only for the `<Text>` there is `TextStyle`.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: This doesn't help, I have updated my question.